# How to solve u[t,x] numerically in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica. I want to solve u[t,x] numerically.

```
b==1; rs==0.05;

chi = Sqrt[x^2 + b^2 - (2 rs)/b(Sqrt[x^2 + b^2] - x)] + rs;
bi = (x^2 + b^2/2 - 2 rs (Sqrt[x^2 + b^2] - x)) (1/x + 
 1/(b - rs/b (Sqrt[x^2 + b^2] - x))(b/rs (1 - x/Sqrt[x^2 + b^2])^-1));
ic = u[0, x] == Sin[x];
bc = {u[t, 1] == 0, u[t, 10] == 0}
eqqu = chi D[u[t, x], t] + bi D[u[t,x], x] + u[t, x] == 0;

 sol = NDSolve[{eqqu, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, 0.5, 5}, {x, 0.5, 10},Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> 10}}]
```

Error message:

> NDsolve: Warning : boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
>
> [NDSolve: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 71544.83329036048' at t=5.' in the direction of independent variable x is much than the prescribe error tolerance. Grid spacing with 45 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precisioon. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxSteSize or Minpoints methods options.

Comment: Better to ask here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Incorrect syntax. First line should be `b=1; rs=0.05;`. Single `=` is `Set`; double is `Equal`.

Comment: I have changed to equal sign, but still getting the same error.